# Flask not finding app route when using Apache

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I am trying to run a python script that takes data collected in javascript, processes it in python, then inserts it into a database. I'm running the webpage on Apache, and I know the insertEngagement() function works to connect to my database.

However, when I use the following AJAX request to send the data to the python file, the app.run() starts but never goes into the insertNewData() function. I'm guessing this has something to do with the path I'm using? Any help would be appreciated!

This is my AJAX request in /home/webpage/script.js:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/home/pythonScripts/processdata.cgi/process",
        data: { employeeText: input1, customerText: input2, chatData: otherData},
        type: "POST",
        success: callbackFunc
    });
```

Then my python is in /home/pythonScripts/processdata.cgi:

```
#!C:\path\to\python\Python37\python.exe

import sys
import getopt
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import mysql.connector as conn
#insertdata is another file with functions in it
import insertdata

from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for,request
from flask import make_response
app = Flask(__name__)

def htmlTop():
    print("""Content-type:text/html\n\n
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                    <title>My server-side template</title>
                </head>
                <body>""")

def htmlTail():
    print("""</body>
        </html>""")


@app.route("/home/pythonScripts/processdata.cgi/process", methods=['GET','POST'])
def insertNewData():
    print ("Started insert new data")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print ("Inside conditional")
        employeeText = request.form['employeeText']
        customerText = request.form['customerText']
        chatData = request.form['chatData']

        # ... use data from request 

        return "Success"
    else:
      return "Error"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  try:
      htmlTop()
      app.run(debug=True)
      htmlTail()
  except:
      cgi.print_exception()
```

Also I am using .cgi because I was unable to configure Apache to run a python script rather than just returning the text file.

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative answer, if this isn't production and you're using an Ubuntu system, I managed to get a Flask app running in a matter of days.

Here is a link to the tutorial I followed;

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

I understand it doesn't answer your question but I found it useful the first time round and it worked without any problems, using forms, requesting API data and printing using Jinja template engine for example.

You can also use a whole host of other developed plugins for user management and logins, authentication, but the best part is, anything you can do with Python, can be ordered via a web based application, so when you get a grasp of how it all works, there is very little you CAN'T do.

In response to the question, I personally used Gunicorn as a go between and use Nginx as a reverse proxy. But there is no reason why Apache cannot substitute Nginx in that line-up that I'm aware of.